# Are there any random variables so that $\mathrm{E}[XY]$ exists, but $\mathrm{E}[X]$ or $\mathrm{E}[Y]$ doesn't?

Tags: probability, random

Are there any random variables so that $\mathrm{E}[XY]$ exists, but $\mathrm{E}[X]$ or $\mathrm{E}[Y]$ doesn't?

Comment: What about a trivial case where $X=0$ and $Y$ has no expected value?

Comment: Do you know someone called Tzwick who just asked "Are there any random variables so that E[X] and E[Y] exist but E[XY] doesn't?"

Comment: @Henry: the provided e-mails are the same and both are unregistered. I've merged the accounts. @Tzwick: to stop from making more duplicate accounts, please register your account.

Answer (score 8):

Yes.  For example take $C$ as a Cauchy random variable and independently $H$ as $0$ or $1$ with equal probability.

Let $X=CH$ and $Y=C(1-H)$.

Then the expectations of $X$ and $Y$ would be half the expectation of $C$, except that it does not exist, while $XY=0$ and so $E[XY]=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, let Y be the value $2^n$ with probability $\frac{1}{2^n}$.  Let $X=1/Y$.  Then $XY=1$ and $E(X)=\frac{4}{3}$ exists, but $E(Y)$ does not exist.

Comment: $Y$ definition is not complete. From your definition it is clear that $P(Y=2^n)=\frac{1}{2^n}$, but this leaves $1-2^{-n}$ of probability mass unassigned.